# swift: number of files that can be downloading at the same time

Tags: ios, swift

I have collection view with sections and cells.

I use this code to download files:

```
let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "com.example.DownloadTaskExample.background")
backgroundSession = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue())

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let url = URL(string: "link")!
    let downloadTaskLocal = self.backgroundSession.downloadTask(with: url)
    self.allDownloadTasks.append(downloadTaskLocal) // Add a new task to the array
    downloadTaskLocal.resume()
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession,
                    downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask,
                    didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64,
                    totalBytesWritten: Int64,
                    totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64){

        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {() -> Void in

            if let visibleIndexPath = self.collectionView?.indexPathsForVisibleItems {
                for visibleIndexPath in visibleIndexPath {
                    if (downloadTask.currentRequest?.url?.lastPathComponent == "\(visibleIndexPath.section)\(visibleIndexPath.row).zip") {

            self.progressOfDownload.append("\(Int(CGFloat(totalBytesWritten) / CGFloat(totalBytesExpectedToWrite) * 100.0))%")

}
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

But if I will click on cells my files start download. But I want to click on one cell (start showing progress) and if after that I click on different cell I don't want to show progress in this cell until first file not downloaded. In other words. I want to downloading one file at time and if user click to another cell this download should be in queue. How to do it?

Comment: You can use URLSessionConfiguration to set number of items to download at a time.
        sessionConfigue.httpMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 1 so it will start single task at a time.

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code, it will manage all your download task

```
var isDownloading = false{
    didSet{
        if isDownloading == false{
            //remove downloadedTask
            if allDownloadTasks.count > 0{
                allDownloadTasks.removeFirst()
            }
        }
    }
}

var allDownloadTasks:[URLSessionDownloadTask] = []{
    didSet{
        if isDownloading == false{
            //start next Download
            startNextDownload()
        }
    }
}

func startNextDownload(){
    //start download task
    if allDownloadTasks.count > 0{
        let downloadTask = allDownloadTasks[0]
        downloadTask.resume()
    }
}
```

in CollectionViewDidSelect method

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let url = URL(string: "link")!
    let downloadTaskLocal = self.backgroundSession.downloadTask(with: url)
    self.allDownloadTasks.append(downloadTaskLocal) // Add a new task to the array
}
```

Comment: I should add your code  after line: `allDownloadTasks.append(downloadTaskLocal)`?

Comment: you just need to add isDownloading , allDownloadTask variables & startNextDownload function.